# Second activity doesn't start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I read a lot of here but nothing would help me.

As the title says i'm programming a simple android application with two activities. The first includes a button. By clicking this the second activity should be activated. But nothing happens.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.schnitzeljagd"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.schnitzeljagd.UiActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <activity
        android:name="com.example.schnitzeljagd.showArchivements"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My first activity is:

```
package com.example.schnitzeljagd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class UiActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ui_activitiy);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, showArchivements.class);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(intent);  }
    });
    }

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
   }


}
```

And my second:

```
package com.example.schnitzeljagd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class showArchivements extends Activity{


  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ui_activitiy);



    }

}
```

Has anyone some ideas what might be wrong here?

Sorry for my creepy english and thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inflating the uiactivity again in the showArchivements.

Try this:

```
public class showArchivements extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout. _YOUR_SHOW_ARCHIVEMENTS_LAYOUT_NAME_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using the same layout for both `Activities`. Actually second `Activity` is opened normally, but you don't see any difference because the layout is the same. So just create another layout for the second `Activity` and use it at the `setContentView` call.

Answer (score 0):

Change `R.layout.ui_activitiy` to other in showArchivements activity.

Answer (score 0):

Put this as your Click pulse in the activity where your button is? In your main now.

**"name of the activity where you are in now".this, "name of the activity you want to open".class**

```
    public class OnClick implements OnClickListener {   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(**main_activity.this, second_activity.class**));
    }
}
```

Maybe you can put one textView in your onCreate in the second activity, then you know for sure that something need to pop up after clicking ;-)

And put the onClick part (shown above..) after your onCreateOptionsMenu. And delete the onClick part in your onCreate.

And your first and second activity needs another layout .xml

Try this, I hope it work! And when it work, let it know! Mark this post as solved! :-)

Goodluck,

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

[**Thus demo application tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/) show you how to interact with activity, when a button is clicked, navigate from current screen (current activity) to another screen (another activity).

**UiActivity.java**

```
package com.example.schnitzeljagd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class UiActivity extends Activity {

 private Button next;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.ui_activity_one);

   next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, showArchivements.class);
       startActivity(intent); 
       }
    });
   }

  @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
  }
}
```

**showArchivements.java**

```
package com.example.schnitzeljagd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

 public class showArchivements extends Activity{


 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.ui_activity_two);

  }

 }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.schnitzeljagd"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="8"
   android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.schnitzeljagd.UiActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity
           android:name="com.example.schnitzeljagd.showArchivements"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
       </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```